# How to pass Controller method using ajax in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function index() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/admin_dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('teacher_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?teacher/teacher_dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('student_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?student/student_dashboard', 'refresh');

    if ($this->session->userdata('parent_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?parents/parents_dashboard', 'refresh');

    $this->load->view('backend/login');
}

function ajax_login() {
    $response = array();
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;
    $login_status = $this->validate_login($email, $password);
    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
    if ($login_status == 'success') {
        $response['redirect_url'] = '';

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I want to pass index() through $response['redirect_url'] = ''; how to pass? i already tried by creating routes but not working.

Answer (score 0):

`index()` is a function, which according to your code either redirects the user or shows a page. Neither are good for an ajax response as the redirection or view will only occur or render in the ajax request not the users viewport.

I assume you want to add the logic in your index function without repeating yourself too much. Simple solution is to make a function for redirect.

Create a helper and put this function in it:

```
function group_redirect() {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->helper('url');

    if ($ci->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        return base_url() . 'index.php?admin/admin_dashboard';

    if ($ci->session->userdata('teacher_login') == 1)
        return base_url() . 'index.php?teacher/teacher_dashboard';

    if ($ci->session->userdata('student_login') == 1)
        return base_url() . 'index.php?student/student_dashboard';

    if ($ci->session->userdata('parent_login') == 1)
        return base_url() . 'index.php?parents/parents_dashboard';

    return false;
}
```

Then the rest is easy:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->load->helper('name_of_helper_with_function');
}

public function index() {

    $redir = group_redirect();

    if ($redir) {
        redirect($redir);
    }

    $this->load->view('backend/login');
}

function ajax_login() {
    $response = array();
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;
    $login_status = $this->validate_login($email, $password);
    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
    if ($login_status == 'success') {
        $response['redirect_url'] = $redir;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```